# Fail to Increase Hive Mapper Tasks?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a managed Hive table, which contains only one 150MB file. I then do "select count(*) from tbl" to it, and it uses 2 mappers. I want to set it to a bigger number.

First I tried 'set mapred.max.split.size=8388608;', so hopefully it will use 19 mappers. But it only uses 3. Somehow it still split the input by 64MB. I also used 'set dfs.block.size=8388608;', not working either.

Then I tried a vanilla map-reduce job to do the same thing. It initially uses 3 mappers, and when I set mapred.max.split.size, it uses 19. So the problem lies in Hive, I suppose.

I read some of the Hive source code, like CombineHiveInputFormat, ExecDriver, etc. can't find a clue.

What else settings can I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I combined @javadba 's answer with that I received from Hive mailing list, here's the solution:

```
set hive.input.format=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat;
set mapred.map.tasks = 20;
select count(*) from dw_stage.st_dw_marketing_touch_pi_metrics_basic;
```

From the mailing list:

> It seems that HIVE is using the old Hadoop MapReduce API and so mapred.max.split.size won't work.

I would dig into source code later.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following:

```
set hive.merge.mapfiles=false;
set hive.input.format=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat;
```

Comment: Setting hive.input.format will increase mappers to the number of input files. But still cannot split into smaller tasks. So maybe I also need to adjust the upstream query which generates the target table, i.e. increase the number reducers.