# Setting the number of map and reduce tasks dynamically for a Hive query

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, spotfire

I have reports generated on Spotfire from the tables stored on Hive. Concurrent users will be accessing the Hive table from different reports. I need to improve the read performance of Spotfire by allocating the map and reduce tasks dynamically for each report or each query. Is there a way to accomplish this? Or are there any alternatives?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20816726/fail-to-increase-hive-mapper-tasks